# Problems with output order after returning multiple values through a subroutine in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, hash, subroutine

I am having a bit of a problem figuring out how to correctly syntax a subroutine that returns multiple values. Say we have a file that has the below format from which I want to parse the values:

```
Id: Animal1
Loc: Area1
Similarity: 15/20

Id: Animal2
Loc: Area2
Similarity: 19/20

Id: Animal3
Loc: Area3
Similarity: 13/20
```

Since I have a couple of files I want to run in the same script, I wanted to read them in in the form of a subroutine. My command however messes up the output order completely. Any ideas about what error in my code might be causing this?

Here is the code that works when not in the subroutine format, starting after I open the file:

```
open($fh, "<", $animal1) || die "Could not open file $animal1/n $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    if($_ =~ /Id:\s+(\S+)/){
        $id= $1;

    }
    if($_ =~ /Loc:\s+(\S+)/){
        $loc{$id}= $1;
    }
    if($_ =~ /Similarity:\s+(\S+)/){
        $simil{$id}= $1;
    }
}

foreach $id(keys %loc){
    print "The $animal is found in $loc{$animal} and is $simil{$animal} similar\n";
}
close $fh;
```

The code in question:

```
open($fh, "<", $animal1) || die "Could not open file $animal1/n $!\n";

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    ($animal, $loc{$animal}, $simil{$animal})= parse_key_file($_);
}

foreach $animal(keys %loc){
    print "The $animal is found in $loc{$animal} and is $simil{$animal} similar\n";
}

sub parse_key_file {
    if($_ =~ /Id:\s+(\S+)/){
        $id= $1;
        next;
    }
    if($_ =~ /Loc:\s+(\S+)/){
        $loc{$id}= $1;
        next;
    }
    if($_ =~ /Similarity:\s+(\S+)/){
        $simil{$id}= $1;
        next;
    }
    return ($id, $loc{$id}, $simil{$id});
}
```

Thank you !
A.

Answer (score 4):

> My command however makes messes the output order completely. Any ideas about what error in my code might be causing this?

It's not an error in your code (though do heed the suggestions from Dave Cross). It's an error in your understanding about Perl's hash variable type and the `keys` function. The hash type is unordered, and there is no guarantee what order the hash keys will be returned to you in the `keys` function. To return them in a particular order (say, the order they are encountered in your input file), you will have to keep track of it yourself.

```
my (%seen,@order);
sub parse_key_file {
    if($_ =~ /Id:\s+(\S+)/){
        $id= $1;
        if (!$seen{$id}++) {
            push @order, $id;
        }
        next;
    }
    ...
}

foreach $animal (@order) {
    print "The $animal is found in $loc{$animal} and is $simil{$animal} similar\n";
}
```

There is also a module called [`Tie::IxHash`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::IxHash) that provides hash variables that retain the order input of their keys, when you are ready to use Perl modules.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid this is all rather confused. I think that the main problem is your use of global variables. A subroutine should only ever use variables that are either passed into it as parameters or defined within it. Also, storing the data about an animal across three different hashes is a recipe for disaster. As you've seen, you can't guarantee that the different hashes remain in step.

Let's start by writing a subroutine that takes one of your "paragraphs" of data about a single animal and turns it into a hash.

```
sub parse_animal {
  my ($input) = @_;

  my %animal;

  for (split /\n/, $input) {
    next unless /\S/;

    if (/Id:\s+(\S+)/) {
      $animal{id} = $1;
      next;
    }
    if (/Loc:\s+(\S+)/) {
      $animal{loc} = $1;
      next;
    }
    if (/Similarity:\s+(\S+)/) {
      $animal{simil} = $1;
      next;
    }
    warn "Unknown data line: $_";
  }

  return \%animal;
}
```

This looks a lot like your code except it only uses data passed as parameters and it builds and returns a hash of information.

We can test that by putting in a program like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dumper;

my $animal1 = 'animals.dat';

open(my $fh, "<", $animal1) || die "Could not open file $animal1: $!\n";

local $/ = '';

while (<$fh>) {
  my $animal = parse_animal($_);
  say Dumper $animal;
}

sub parse_animal {
  ...
}
```

We're using [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) here to see what you get back from the subroutine. I get this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'loc' => 'Area1',
          'id' => 'Animal1',
          'simil' => '15/20'
        };

$VAR1 = {
          'simil' => '19/20',
          'id' => 'Animal2',
          'loc' => 'Area2'
        };

$VAR1 = {
          'simil' => '13/20',
          'id' => 'Animal3',
          'loc' => 'Area3'
        };
```

So we can see that a) we're parsing the data correctly and b) the data for each animal is staying together in a single hash.

So what to actually to with the data we get back? Well, there are (at least!) a couple of options. And which to choose depends on what you want your program to do.

If you want to process information about the animals in the order that they appear in the input file, then it makes sense to store them in an array.

```
my @animals;

while (<$fh>) {
  push @animals, parse_animal($_);
}

for (@animals) {
  say "The $_->{id} is found in $_->{loc} and is $_->{simil} similar";
}
```

Another option might be to store them in a hash (keyed, perhaps, by ID):

```
my %animals;

while (<$fh>) {
  my $animal = parse_animal($_);
  $animals{$animal->{id}} = $animal;
}

say Dumper \%animals;
```

But hopefully, this has given you enough information to get you unstuck.